# Rails Rake Task CSV Import is slow

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I am working through importing csv files through rake tasks (as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602049/rails-rake-task-drop-table-and-import-from-csv) the other day).

```
namespace :csvimport do

  desc "Import Products CSV Data."
  task :products => :environment do

    ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table products

    require 'csv'
    csv_file_path = '/home/jay/workspace/db/import_tables/products.csv'
    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|
      p = Product.create!({
          :product_id => row[0],
          :product_name => row[1],
        }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This works great for small file sizes (say 10000 rows). But when I try with a larger file upwards of a million it is taking a very long time. I am also getting no feedback that the process is happening. If I go into pgAdmin3 and using SQL `SELECT count(*) FROM sales;` I can see it is going up 10 or 20 rows per second.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a better way to do this? I can just import the data directly through pgAdmin SQL which is very fast (a couple of minutes) but I want to build a solution so that when I go to production I can do this through an admin interface.

In saying this, once I go to production I will attempt to only import new data from one of our older systems when bringing it into rails.

Also, how can I just kill the existing rake task? Better way then just 'x' out of terminal.

Comment: ok... standard 'ctrl+c' to abort the rake task

Comment: Do you really need to `Product.create!`? Things will go much faster if you can send the CSV straight into the database and bypass ActiveRecord altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COPY`.

The Ruby `Pg` gem [supports this with the `copy_data` method of `PG::Connection`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#copy_data-instance_method).

The gem comes with examples of how to use it.

To learn more about improving insertion rates in general, see: [How to speed up insertion performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670) . In particular, see the advice re batching work into transactions.